# Use of "dd" instead of "of" or "dated" in constructions of the type "Document Version 4.0 dd 21-April-2020"

Tags: dates

I'm a translator and at one translation bureau where I work one of the editors changes the preposition "of" or the word "dated" in time-related constructions to "**dd**", in this way:

> "Document Version 4.0 **dd** 21-April-2020" (instead of "of 21-April-2020")

I have a twopartite question:

Would this be readily understood by the native speaker?

If not, how can I persuade them that the standard way is to write **of** or **dated**?

I came across this [statement](https://www.proz.com/kudoz/english-to-spanish/business-commerce-general/4521262-dd.html) on Proz.com: "d.d. (or dd) is a pretty standard English business acronym meaning "dated" but I personally have never come across this acronym in my life before I started working at this translation bureau.

Comment: I have never seen "dd" used in that manner. I usually see "dd" in instructions on how to enter a date on a form, e.g. "Date of birth __________ (**dd** / mm /yyyy.)" This tells the reader to write, for example, 14/08/1998

Comment: I have just found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DD - in a huge list of examples, there is no entry for "dated".

Comment: [d.d. (or dd) is a pretty standard English business acronym meaning "dated).](https://www.proz.com/kudoz/english-to-spanish/business-commerce-general/4521262-dd.html) But I don't believe it's remotely "standard" - so far as I'm concerned it has little to no currency.

Comment: Even if this is (or was) common practice in certain business settings, it could still be unknown to most speakers of English.

Comment: *If not, how can I persuade them that the standard way is to write of or dated?* This belongs on Workplace SE or Interpersonal Skills SE, not here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Acronym Finder](https://www.acronymfinder.com/DD.html), lists 'dated' as 14th in its list of (215) expansions for the abbreviation dd. (It does not list normally upper-cased and normally lower-cased exemplars separately.)

While 'two-digit day' is the first related expansion, 'due date', 'delivered', and 'delivery date' also rank higher than the desired interpretation, while 'digital data' is another nearby potentially confusible expansion.

Admittedly, the expansion 'dated' is in the 'most frequent' Likert-style classification (A-F), but the Gricean maxim of manner (here, 'avoid ambiguity') might be invoked if there is a better candidate here.

'Of' is, in common with almost all prepositions, highly polysemous (here: written, rubber-stamped, dated or even filed on the date given?), but 'dated' is an unmistakable form of 'dated' (and not much longer). Mind you, compression acceptability depends on context. If your regular audience understands 'CI-1010', only use '1H-imidazole-1-ethanol,alpha-[[(2-bromoethyl)amino]methyl]-2-nitro-,mono-hydrobromide' with outsiders. You can use MS (judiciously) if you're a Master of Science teaching Management Studies in Mississippi, even with a nasty ailment, and you might even have discovered an old piece of writing in the library, but medical workers shouldn't use MS for morphine sulphate according to the [Institute for Safe Medication Practices](https://www.ismp.org/recommendations/error-prone-abbreviations-list).

Comment: Thank you, Edwin! I will try using **dated** based on the Gricean maxims. Did you ever come across this use of **dd** in real documents before, or was it new to you?

Comment: I think I remember dtd (this was before the DTD's appeared); d was always 'died'.

Answer (score 0):

"dd" is the abbreviation of the Latin "de die", meaning "of the day", i.e. "dated".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).